# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 - AngularJS + Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, http, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a Post request here but not succeeding with it.

Angularjs code:

```
function Login(username, password, callback) {

      $http.post('http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/login', { username: username, password: password })

            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                       callback(response);
            });

    }
```

Server code:

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestBody Login login) {
    if (login.username.equals("test") && login.password.equals("test")) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        return "not success";
    }
}
```

Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/basic-web-app/login`. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: For authentication and authorization I would recommend using Spring-security rather than manually doing it the way you are doing.

Comment: I know , but it is just a school project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a Post

```
 $http.post(
```

and Spring MVC expects a GET

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I suggest to change your Controller definition to a POST

Comment: Thank you! It seems like this was the problem. Now the angular part expects me to return some kind of success reposnse to continue with the login. Any hint about that?